# XSLT to convert elements in a concatenated line

Tags: xslt

I have this situation:

Two variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="varDep" select="DepAir"/>
<xsl:variable name="varArr" select="ArrAir"/>
```

Value of variables:

```
 <testa>
      <DepAir>SDU</DepAir>
      <DepAir>CGH</DepAir>
 </testa>
 <testb>
      <ArrAir>CGH</ArrAir>
      <ArrAir>SDU</ArrAir>
 </testb>
```

And I need transform in a concatenated line, like this:

```
<db:P_IAT>SDU;CGH;CGH;SDU;</db:P_IAT>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: We really do need to see more XSLT (ideally a complete one) because currently for the `varDep` variable to select anything, the current context would need to be `testa`. And for the `varArr` to select anything the current context would need to be `testb`. This suggests that variables have different scopes, meaning you could not use both in one single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Kind dynamic way will be to put loop for `DepAir` and `ArrAir` inside above variables as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="varDep">
    <xsl:for-each select="//DepAir">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ';')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>    

<xsl:variable name="varArr">
    <xsl:for-each select="//ArrAir">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ';')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>            
</xsl:variable>
```

And then use `concat` inside required node:

```
<required_node><xsl:value-of select="concat($varDep, $varArr)"/></required_node>
```

***Note!*** In next questions please put your XSL (what you have tried) to avoid "Down Votes". Hope it will help in your case.